# std::pair substitution failed with std::size_t

Tags: c++, templates, std-pair, forwarding-reference

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t> func(const std::vector<int>& numbers, int target) {
    for(std::size_t i =0; i < numbers.size(); i++)
    {   
      for(std::size_t j = i; j < numbers.size(); j++)
      {   
        if(numbers[i] + numbers[j] == target)
          return std::make_pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>(i,j);
      }   
    }   
    return std::make_pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>(0,0);
}
```

Error:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘std::pair<long unsigned int, long unsigned int> func(const std::vector<int>&, int)’:
test.cpp:12:62: error: no matching function for call to ‘make_pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>(std::size_t&, std::size_t&)’
           return std::make_pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>(i,j);
                                                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/utility:70:0,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:524:5: note: candidate: template<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr std::pair<typename std::__decay_and_strip<_Tp>::__type, typename std::__decay_and_strip<_T2>::__type> std::make_pair(_T1&&, _T2&&)
     make_pair(_T1&& __x, _T2&& __y)
     ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:524:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp:12:62: note:   cannot convert ‘i’ (type ‘std::size_t {aka long unsigned int}’) to type ‘long unsigned int&&’
           return std::make_pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>(i,j);
                                                          ^
```

Why does it try to substitute with `unsigned long int` when we have clearly mentioned the type in templated `pair` and also the datatype of `i` and `j`?

Comment: `std::make_pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>` means `make_pair(size_t&&, size_t&&)` how do you want to bind Lvalues (like `i`, `j`) to Rvalue references ?

Comment: Change `return std::make_pair<std::size_t, std::size_t>(i,j);` to `return {i, j};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you specifying template argument as `std::size_t`, the type of function parameter of `std::make_pair` becomes `std::size_t&&`, i.e. an rvalue-reference; `i` and `j` are lvalues and can't be bound to rvalue-reference.

Just letting `std::make_pair` do the template argument deduction like `std::make_pair(i,j)` (template parameter is `std::size_t&`, function parameter is `std::size_t&`) would be fine. `std::make_pair` takes [forwarding references](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references), it's supposed to accept both lvalues and rvalues (for `std::make_pair(0,0)`, template parameter is `std::size_t`, function parameter is `std::size_t&&`).

Comment: I want to read more about this. cppreference doesn't explained it well.

Comment: @InQusitive More about [forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references).